# Can the multivariate normal distribution be one dimensional?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Can the the multivariate normal distribution be one dimensional? Or should you then just use the normal distribution? I mean does an one dimensional multivariate normal even make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common definition of a multivariate normal distribution actually explicitly uses the definition of a (one-dimensional) normal distribution:

> Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be an $n$-dimensional random variable. Then $X$ is multivariate normal distributed if 
>   $$
> c_1X_1+\cdots+c_nX_n
> $$
>   is (one-dimensional) normal distributed for every choice of $c_1,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

So I guess with this definition you can give sense to the term "one-dimensional multivariate" normal distribution meaning that you put $n=1$ in the above definition, but this just coincides with the usual (one-dimensional) normal distribution.

Comment: Of course. Multivariate -> univariate.